# Can Func return multiple values in C#?

Tags: c#, func

I tried this code:

```
Func<int, int> f3 = (int x) => x * 3;
f3 += (int x) => x * 4;
Console.WriteLine(f3(5));
```

I expect that the output would be:
15
20
But I only get 20.

Comment: How could the output be `15,20`? The output should be an `int`. So it cannot emit two...

Comment: By using `+=` he's creating a multicast delegate whose both delegates return their respective values. Technically this multicast delegate can then return two values, one by one, if you ask it for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could say yes, function can return multi values, by Tuple(and ValueTuple) or IEnumerable ect.

but in your example you want to the contrary: run some functions on one value.

where you place new function in the same variable, The first function is run over. also in += in multicasting the return-value return only from the last function.

How I see it:

```
var listFunctions = new List<System.Func<int, int>>();

listFunctions.Add(x => x * 3);
listFunctions.Add(x => x * 4);

listFunctions.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine( x(5)));
```

Comment: no this not an answer the OP is trying to understand why  !!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `+=` is just a syntactic sugar in this context, so let's rewrite the code to show explicit method calls:

```
Func<int, int> f3 = x => x * 3;
f3 = (Func<int, int>)Delegate.Combine(f3, (Func<int, int>)(x => x * 4));
Console.WriteLine(f3.Invoke(5));
```

There are four reasons why only one value is printed instead of two:

- `f3` is `Func<int, int>`, meaning it has one `int` argument and returns an `int`. You call `f3` once, so you'll only get one `int`.
- [*Delegate.Combine*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/30cyx32c(v=vs.110).aspx) creates a new multicast delegate with the invocation lists of the arguments combined, which is then stored to `f3`. Invoking the delegate invokes all functions in its invocation list, and it happens so that only the value returned from the last function in the list is returned from the whole call.
- You are calling *WriteLine* on a single value (`int`), so only one integer is printed.
- The closest you can get to returning multiple values from a method call is using tuples. Methods in .NET cannot return multiple values natively.

If you are trying to use *Delegate.Combine* (`+=`) expecting to be able to access all returned values from the invocation list, you are using a wrong method. *System.MulticastDelegate* isn't suited for this kind of invocation.

There are many ways to solve this problem. One is using a list of functions (or a custom class with a list of functions) and invoke them all separately.

Another way is to access all delegates in the invocation list and invoke them manually:

```
public static object[] AggregateInvoke(this Delegate del, params object[] args)
{
    Delegate[] invlist = del.GetInvocationList();
    object[] results = new object[invlist.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < invlist.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = invlist[i].DynamicInvoke(args);
    }
    return results;
}

public static TRet[] AggregateInvoke<TArg,TRet>(this Func<TArg, TRet> del, TArg arg)
{
    Delegate[] invlist = del.GetInvocationList();
    TRet[] results = new TRet[invlist.Length];
    for(int i = 0; i < invlist.Length; i++)
    {
        results[i] = ((Func<TArg, TRet>)invlist[i]).Invoke(arg);
    }
    return results;
}
```

The first method works on all delegates and the second only on one-argument functions like in your example. I don't recommend using this instead of normal calls, because it is not a way one usually calls a delegate. I recommend using the first approach.

Answer (score -1):

You can use tuple(.Net 4.0) to return multiple values from function.

```
static void Main() { 
// Create three-item tuple. 
Tuple<int, string, bool> tuple = new Tuple<int, string, bool>(1, "cat", true); 
// Access tuple properties. 
if (tuple.Item1 == 1) { Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item1); }
 if (tuple.Item2 == "dog") { Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item2); } 
if (tuple.Item3) { Console.WriteLine(tuple.Item3); } 
}
```

This is how you can return tuple object from function.

```
    public  Tuple<T1,String> Create<T1>(T1 item1) { 
return new Tuple<T1>(item1,"string"); 
}
```